# Get last item of array returned by find command in bash

Tags: bash

I have command:

```
bigfiles=$(find "${path}/" -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -2 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //')
```

Now I want to get last item like

```
anotherfile=$bigfiles[1]
```

and it seems to be empty

How to get n-th element of results from `find` command ?

Comment: `$bigfiles` is not array.

Comment: your problem is getting the nth line from an input or convert the multi-line into shell array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using `mapfile` which is a bash4+ feature, might do what you wanted.

```sh
mapfile -t bigfiles < <(find "${path}/" -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -2 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //')

anotherfile=${bigfiles[-1]}
echo "$anotherfile"
```

- `-1` is the last element/item in the array.
- If you're just interested in the last item with find's output , you can probably pipe the output to `tail` or maybe `head` depending on what you're trying to do with it.